# chainerを使ったganのエラーについて

Tags: python, ubuntu, chainer

以下のgithubのプログラムを実行したいです。
https://github.com/musyoku/improved-gan/
エラーの内容も理解できていない状況です。自分の経験の足りなさを自覚しています。
引数が足りないよとの事を言われてそうなのですが、どこで関数を呼び出しているのかも分かりません。
どなたか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

```
$ python model.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 118, in <module>
    generator.build()
  File "/sequential/sequential.py", line 83, in build
    self.from_json(json)
  File "/sequential/sequential.py", line 109, in from_json
    self.from_dict(dict_array)
  File "/sequential/sequential.py", line 116, in from_dict
    link = self.layer_to_chainer_link(layer)
  File "/sequential/sequential.py", line 76, in layer_to_chainer_link
    return layer.to_link()
  File "/sequential/layers.py", line 157, in to_link
   return chainer.links.Linear(**args)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bias'
```

Comment: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bias'` は、「`'bias'`という不要な引数を受け取った」、というエラーです。

Comment: そのエラーについては理解していますが、どこをどのように改善すればよいか分からず困っています。お力貸して貰えてないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

エラーを発生させている原因箇所が[こちら](https://github.com/musyoku/improved-gan/blob/ba1e09faff289c3ff63eb1f331ccb0779e5522a6/sequential/layers.py#L157)で、`sequential.py`の`Linear`クラスにおける`bias`を、[biasというパラメータを受け取らない](http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.links.Linear.html#chainer-links-linear)`chainer.links.Linear`に渡しているのが原因です。

そもそもの原因として、https://github.com/musyoku/improved-gan/ 自体のメンテナンスが2年近く前で停止しているので、当時は動いていたものの最新版のChainerでは動かない、のではないでしょうか。

修正方法として以下の2種類が考えられます。

- https://github.com/musyoku/improved-gan/ 全体を最新版のChainerで動くように作り変える。
- 古いバージョンのChainerをインストールして、動くか確認する。